# get char on screen

Tags: c++, ncurses

I've looked through the NCurses function list, and I can't seem to find a function that returns the characters already printed on the screen. Is there an accessible value for the char stored in each character cell? If not, is there a similar function in the Windows terminal?

I want to use this to replace all the characters on the screen of a certain value (ex: all the `a`'s) with a different character, or with new attributes.

Comment: You should post your answer as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I've removed the answer from your question, as answers belong in answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `inch()` gets the character and returns it as a `chtype`. Use `winch()` to get a character from a window other than `stdscr`.

Comment: It'd also be worth adding a link to [some documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/inch.html), as well as the `mvinch` and `mvwinch` functions, which are highly related if not identical.